# Teniendo una lista de palabras, ¿Cómo obtener las que contengan letras de una lista sin importar el orden? al menos una vez cada letra

Tags: regex

Usando expresiones regulares (Regex), se busca filtrar palabras que tengan al menos una vez cada letra de una lista (entre 2 y 5 caracteres mas o menos) sin importar el orden en el que aparezcan.

Por ejemplo, teniendo la siguiente lista:

```
mario diente armario caballo motor mariposa crema café estrella explosión guitarra plástico navaja martillo libros lápiz lapicera aluminio embarcación letra agujeta
```

quisiera encontrar las palabras que contienen al menos una vez: `a`, `i` y `l`
El resultado sería:

```
martillo # -> .a..ill. Esta parte es comentario
lapicera # -> la.i...a
aluminio # -> al..i.i.
```

Se puede saber si una palabra tiene al menos una letra con `[ail]` pero esto no garantiza que tenga al menos una vez a cada una.

Se puede saber de forma ordenada con `a\w*i\w*l` pero serviría solo con el mismo orden y se tendría que agregar cada permutación por separado.

Usar `lookahead` parece útil para esto, esta `\b\w*(?=[ial])\w*\b` encuentra solo si hay al menos una letra de la lista, pero no al menos una vez cada una (debe contener las tres al mismo tiempo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando expresiones regulares, he aquí una idea que funciona:

```
import re

palabras = "mario diente armario caballo motor mariposa crema café estrella explosión guitarra plástico navaja martillo libros lápiz lapicera aluminio embarcación letra agujeta"
regex = re.compile(r"\b(?:[^a]+|[^i]+|[^l]+)\b")

filtradas = [p for p in palabras.split() if not re.match(regex, p)]
```

Resultado:

```
['martillo', 'lapicera', 'aluminio']
```

### Cómo funciona

La idea clave es buscar **lo contrario** de lo que pretendías, lo cual es mucho más sencillo de expresar con una regex. Lo que vamos a buscar es una palabra que **no contenga** alguna de esas tres letras.

La expresión regular para "una palabra que no contenga la letra a" es sencilla de escribir: `\b[^a]+\b`, de forma análoga para que no contenga la "i" o la "l". Si queremos que no contenga *una cualquiera* de esas tres, juntamos las tres expresiones con el separador `|` (or) dentro de un grupo de no captura, y movemos los delimitadores de palabra (`\b`) fuera de ese grupo:

```
\b(?:[^a]+|[^i]+|[^l]+)\b
```

Esta expresión captura las palabras que no tengan a, o no tengan i o no tengan l. Pero si una palabra tiene las tres letras (a, i, l) entonces esa palabra no será capturada. Es decir, hace justo lo contrario de lo que queríamos.

Por tanto evaluamos `re.match()` sobre cada una de las palabras y nos quedamos con las que no encajen.

En el fondo hemos usado una especie de "ley de De Morgan". En vez de mirar `((contiene a) and (contiene i) and (continene l))` estamos mirando `not ((contiene a) or (contiene i) or (contiene l))` y hacemos esto porque la condición "or" se puede expresar con regexp mientras que la "and" no, porque nos forzaría un orden.

### Bonus

Otra solución que no hace `palabras.split()` sino que trabaja directamente con la cadena de palabras (y que puede por tanto encontrarlas aunque no estén delimitadas por espacios sino por cualquier otro caracter de "word-boundary", es la siguiente. Es mucho más *hackish*:

```
palabras = """
mario. diente, armario (caballo) motor [mariposa] crema;
café estrella explosión guitarra. plástico
navaja {martillo} libros, lápiz; lapicera; aluminio.
embarcación letra agujeta"""

filtrado = [p for p in re.split(regex, palabras) if p]
```

Resultado:

```
['martillo', 'lapicera', 'aluminio']
```

#### Cómo funciona

Aunque la idea se basa en el mismo principio, aquí se ha usado `re.split()` en vez de `re.match()`.

Lo que hace `re.split()` es dividir la cadena `palabras` por todos los puntos en los que la expresión regular encaje, es decir por todas las partes en las que haya una secuencia de caracteres delimitada por un word-boundary que no contenga "a" o "i" o "j".

Retorna una lista con los trozos resultantes, que serán justamente las partes en las que había secuencias de caracteres que contienen "a", "i" y "j", o bien cadenas vacías que resultan cuando hay dos matches seguidos y por tanto el trozo entre ambos es "". Quitamos esas cadenas vacías (con `if p`) y tenemos el resultado buscado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta no se me había ocurrido pensarlo con lógica negativa, ¿Porqué en el `bonus` automáticamente se eliminan los caracteres especiales sin especificarlo?

Comment: Es un accidente feliz. Debido a que `[^a+]` captura todo lo que no es una "a" y por tanto también la coma, el punto, etc. Es un poco lioso de explicar. Imagina que la cadena es `"mario; diente; lapicera; letra"`. En una cadena así la `regex` encajaría con las sub-cadenas: `'mario; diente; '` por un lado (pues es voraz), con la `'; '` al final de lapicera por otro, y finalmente con `"letra"`. Lo único en lo que no ha encajado ha sido con "lapicera" (sigue...)

Comment: Al usar `.split()` obtienes los trozos resultantes de partir la cadena por los puntos en los que se ha producido el encaje (retirando de la misma los propios encajes). Así que en este ejemplo el resultado de `.split()` sería: la cadena vacía que hay delante de `'mario; diente; '`, la cadena "lapicera" (porque es lo que hay entre `'mario; diente; '` y el siguiente encaje `'; '`) , la cadena vacía que hay entre `'; '` y `'letra'`, y la cadena vacía que hay después de `'letra'`. Es decir, el resultado de split es `['', 'lapicera', '', '']`. Tras eliminar las vacias, queda "lapicera".

Answer (score 2):

> **Nota**. Tras publicar esta respuesta el OP aclaró que lo que busca tiene que usar expresiones regulares. He escrito otra respuesta con una versión que las usa. No obstante he decidido dejar esta respuesta porque creo que usar conjuntos es mucho más claro y legible (y probablemente más rápido también)

Se trata entonces de determinar si una palabra tiene **las tres letras** dadas (al menos una vez cada una).

Esto es bastante sencillo de resolver si usamos **conjuntos**. El conjunto es un tipo de datos Python muy útil y que suele pasarse por alto.

Si convertimos una palabra en un conjunto, lo que tenemos son las letras que la componen, pero sin que importe su orden y **sin elementos repetidos**. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> set("embarcación")
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 'ó'}
```

Observa que aunque la palabra tenía dos "a", en el conjunto resultante ya solo sale una.

Además los conjuntos permiten operaciones de conjuntos, como la intersección (que se realiza con el operador `&`):

```
>>> set("embarcación") & set("ail")
{'a', 'i'}
```

¡Pues ya lo tenemos! Las tres letras aparecerán en la palabra si la intersección tiene tres elementos.

Por tanto el siguiente código hace lo que se pide:

```
for palabra in palabras.split():
  if len(set(palabra) & set("ail")) == 3:
    print(palabra)
```

Resultado:

```
martillo
lapicera
aluminio
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, me ha faltado también haber aclarado que la respuesta la busco para regex (está en etiqueta), editaré para mencionarlo en la descripción.

Answer (score 0):

Usando esta expresión regular:

> ((?=\w*a)(?=\w*i)(?=\w*l)\w+)

lo haces de forma directa y más eficiente  (codigo en python 3.10):

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = re.compile('((?=\w*a)(?=\w*i)(?=\w*l)\w+)')
>>> result = exp.findall('mario diente armario caballo motor mariposa crema café estrella explosión guitarra plástico navaja martillo libros lápiz lapicera aluminio embarcación letra agujeta platillo')
>>> result
['martillo', 'lapicera', 'aluminio', 'platillo']
```

Sin la necesidad de filtrar hacer un bucle for o cualquier otra operación adicional, ya que dicha expresión regular te ayuda directamente que encuentres todas las palabras que contengan las letras a&i&l evaluando el patrón con las tres letras como si compararas con un & lógico entre todas.